# SQL: Select the next datetime in the future from one of two columns

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table similar to this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| from                | to                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2014-07-01 01:00:00 | NULL                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2015-08-01 02:00:00 | 2015-10-01 02:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2015-09-01 03:00:00 | 2015-10-01 03:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And i need to know the next datetime in the future, which should be: 2015-08-01 02:00:00

*i'm looking for the "correct" answer, ideally without subqueries or joins.*

Comment: a co-worker suggested using CASE, i'll post my results

Comment: Is it always going to be the 'to' column that is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Assuming that `from` is always before `to` for each row, you don't even need LEAST:

```
SELECT MIN(IF(`from` > NOW(), `from`, `to`))
FROM `yourtable`
WHERE `from` > NOW()
   OR `to` > NOW();
```

This works because one of `from` or `to` have to be `> NOW()` or the `WHERE` eliminates that row. So in procedural pseudo code this is like

```
x = ("from" where "from" is > now) and
    ("to" where "from" is < now and "to" > now)
min(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there always a certain amount of time between those two dates? When it is always the same it shouldn't be to hard, because you can use something like this:

```
Update 'table'
Set to = from + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Obviously you can change the number of days that fits for your query.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing a query to get all rows with a null `to` column, as well as a query that gets the minimum date from each row, and then join them together on the condition that the minimum row date is later than the date in the first table:

```
SELECT m.*, t.dateCol
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT LEAST(fromCol, toCol) AS dateCol
  FROM myTable) t ON t.dateCol > m.fromCol AND m.toCol IS NULL;
```

Once you have that, you can group by `fromCol` and get the minimum `dateCol` as the next date:

```
SELECT m.fromCol, MIN(t.dateCol) AS nextDate
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT LEAST(fromCol, toCol) AS dateCol
  FROM myTable) t ON t.dateCol > m.fromCol AND m.toCol IS NULL
GROUP BY m.fromCol;
```

The way that would look in an update is something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable m
JOIN(
   SELECT m.fromCol, MIN(t.dateCol) AS nextDate
   FROM myTable m
   JOIN(
      SELECT LEAST(fromCol, toCol) AS dateCol
      FROM myTable) t ON t.dateCol > m.fromCol AND m.toCol IS NULL
   GROUP BY m.fromCol) t ON t.fromCol = m.fromCol
SET m.toCol = t.nextDate;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/310898/1) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next closest date in each column by using

```
SELECT MIN(from) AS MinFrom, MIN(to) as MinTo FROM TABLENAME
```

Getting the smallest of both is a little harder and requires nesting, but it's doable.

```
SELECT MIN(COM.Dates) FROM (
    SELECT from AS Dates FROM TABLENAME
    UNION
    SELECT to FROM TABLENAME
) AS COM
```

EDIT: Realized that only one overarching MIN was needed.

Comment: Instead of nesting the functions, you can use `LEAST(col1, col2)`.